# Trying to print using window.print() is cropping the content and not creating a second page

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, window

I am trying to print a two page document from my react app, but the content is being cropped and not putting the cropped content onto a second page.

my html:

```
<div
  className="mx-auto flex max-w-[900px] break-before-page flex-col gap-2 space-y-2 p-2 print:grayscale"
  style={{ zoom: "80%" }}
>
  <SafariPrintAlert />
  <styled.SmallButton className={"print:hidden"} onClick={() => window.print()}>
    Print
  </styled.SmallButton>
  <div>
    <div className="flex justify-between">
      <img
        src={query.data.Supplier.Business.logoUrl ?? ""}
        className="my-auto block h-20 object-contain"
        alt={query.data.Supplier.Business.name}
      />
      <div className="flex select-text flex-col">
        <span>{query.data.Supplier.Business.InvoiceAddress.name}</span>
        <span>{query.data.Supplier.Business.InvoiceAddress.street}</span>
        <span>{query.data.Supplier.Business.InvoiceAddress.city}</span>
        <span>{query.data.Supplier.Business.InvoiceAddress.region}</span>
        <span>{query.data.Supplier.Business.InvoiceAddress.postalCode}</span>
        <span>{query.data.Supplier.Business.InvoiceAddress.country}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div className="flex justify-between pt-4">
        {business?.Supplier && query.data.deliveryNumber && (
          <span className="flex">
            Delivery number: {query.data.deliveryNumber}
          </span>
        )}
        <span>{query.data.Supplier.Business.name}</span>
        <span>{query.data.Supplier.Business.email}</span>
        {business?.Supplier && query.data.Supplier.Business.phoneNumber && (
          <span>
            {user?.name} - {query.data.Supplier.Business.phoneNumber}{" "}
          </span>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <styled.BackgroundDivLegacy>
    <SectionHeader
      icon={
        business?.Supplier ? (
          <ProfilePicture
            logoUrl={query.data.Retailer.Business.logoUrl}
            name={query.data.Retailer.Business.name}
          />
        ) : (
          <ProfilePicture
            logoUrl={query.data.Supplier.Business.logoUrl}
            name={query.data.Supplier.Business.name}
          />
        )
      }
      title={
        <styled.H1
          className={classNames(business?.Supplier && "cursor-pointer")}
        >
          {business?.Supplier
            ? query.data.Retailer.Business.name
            : query.data.Supplier.Business.name}
        </styled.H1>
      }
      subtitle={<styled.H6>{generateOrderNumber(query.data)}</styled.H6>}
    />
    <div className="flex flex-wrap gap-2">
      <Badge className="text-secondary">
        Ordered on {dayjs(query.data?.createdAt).format("DD/MM/YY")}
      </Badge>
      {query.data?.confirmedAt && query.data?.paymentDue && (
        <Badge className="text-secondary">
          Payment due on {dayjs(query.data?.paymentDue).format("DD/MM/YY")}
        </Badge>
      )}
      {query.data?.deliveryPlannedAt && (
        <Badge className="text-secondary">
          {renderDeliveryDateTitle(query.data?.fulfillmentType)} on{" "}
          {dayjs(query.data?.deliveryPlannedAt).format("DD/MM/YY")}
        </Badge>
      )}
    </div>
  </styled.BackgroundDivLegacy>

  <OrderSummaryContainer
    items={
      query.data?.OrderItems.map((orderItem) => ({
        description: orderItem.Product.name ?? "",
        quantity: orderItem.quantity,
        cost: formatCurrency(orderItem.price),
        sku: orderItem.Product.sku,
      })) ?? []
    }
    priceProps={
      searchParams?.get("pricing")
        ? {
            delivery:
              business?.Supplier || query.data?.stripeInvoiceId
                ? formatCurrency(
                    query.data?.deliveryCharge,
                    query.data?.currency
                  )
                : undefined,
            subTotal: query.data?.OrderItems
              ? formatCurrency(
                  calculateItemTotal(query.data?.OrderItems),
                  query.data?.currency
                )
              : "",
            ...(query.data?.discountAmount > 0 && {
              discount: {
                value:
                  query.data?.OrderDiscounts?.[0]?.PriceTierDiscountHistory
                    ?.type === "percentage"
                    ? `${query.data?.OrderDiscounts[0].PriceTierDiscountHistory.amount}%`
                    : formatCurrency(
                        query.data?.discountAmount,
                        query.data?.currency
                      ),
                calculatedTotal: formatCurrency(
                  query.data?.discountAmount,
                  query.data?.currency
                ),
              },
            }),
            tax: {
              name: renderTaxName(query.data?.currency),
              percentage: query.data?.vatPercentage?.toString() ?? "",
              total: formatCurrency(
                calculateVatTotal(createOrderCommonParams(query.data)),
                query.data?.currency
              ),
            },
            total: formatCurrency(query.data?.price, query.data?.currency),
          }
        : undefined
    }
  />

  <div className={"pagebreak"}>
    <span style={{ visibility: "hidden" }}>-</span>
  </div>
  <styled.BackgroundDivLegacy className="flex justify-between gap-2">
    <div>
      <OrderAddress
        address={query.data?.DeliveryAddress}
        title="Delivery Address"
      />
    </div>
  </styled.BackgroundDivLegacy>

  {query.data?.deliveryNotes && (
    <styled.BackgroundDivLegacy>
      <styled.H5>Delivery instructions</styled.H5>
      <styled.H6 className="mt-2 whitespace-pre-wrap break-words">
        {query.data.deliveryNotes}
      </styled.H6>
    </styled.BackgroundDivLegacy>
  )}

  <styled.BackgroundDivLegacy className="flex gap-2">
    {["Signature", "Date", "Print Name", "Time"].map((label) => (
      <div key={label} className="block shrink">
        <label>{label}:</label>
        <input className="w-full rounded-md border-2 p-2" placeholder={label} />
      </div>
    ))}
  </styled.BackgroundDivLegacy>
</div>;
```

I have seen some people online suggesting adding in a page break which i have done with the following:

```
 <div className={"pagebreak"}>
    <span style={{ visibility: "hidden" }}>-</span>
  </div>
```

The class `pagebreak` is the following:

```
@media print {
  .pagebreak {
    break-after: auto !important;
    page-break-after: always !important;
    page-break-inside: avoid !important;
  }
}
```

But I am still getting the following output from the print window:

[image]

As you can see, everything below Delivery Address is cropped on that first page